# Azure Web Role-Some files are not being added to cspkg file

Tags: deployment, webrole

Finally after days of trial and error, I managed to get an existing MVC project converted into Azure Web Role. Deployed and it works, mostly.  But my biggest issue is that the cspkg is missing some files that are part of the MVC project (they are listed in csproj).  It appears that some files are being left out randomly.  For example, if a folder has 4 files, I see only one of that included in the cspkg.  Is there a way to force inclusion of these files other than listing them in csproj. I noticed that Visual Studio web role deployment process goes through the list of files in csproj.  When a file listed in csproj is not found, cspkg creation throws errors. So my assuption was that if a file was listed in csproj and if the file actually exists, it should find its way to cspkg.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  Don't know why, but Visual Studio used  tag instead of  tag for some files in vbproj file.